# what is the maximum possible euclidean distance between two vectors, each of whose elements sum to 1

Tags: vectors

I have two n-dim vectors: $V = (v_1,v_2,...v_n)$, $U = (u_1,u_2,...u_n)$ with $0 \leq v_i,u_i \leq 1$ $\forall i$ and $|V|_1, |U|_1 = 1$

What is the maximum possible euclidean distance between the two $||U-V||$ ?

Is it just $\sqrt(2)$ ? (i.e. $v_i = 1, u_j = 1$ $j \neq i$). My intuition is that it is just this, but I don't know how to prove to myself that this is correct.

Comment: I might be getting it wrong but isn't it 2 if in two dimensions (unit circle) if the angel between two unit vectors is 180, so that the distance becomes the diameter which is 2?

Comment: @MathX - in my case it is not a unit vector - the l1 norm (i.e. the sum of elements) is 1. Also all the elements are non-negative. So I don't think what you suggested will work here.